# Is there a good change of variable to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we solve this integral using a good change of variable?

The integral is:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2(x-1)^3}\mathrm{d}x$$

I know how to solve using the way of decomposition, but is there another way?

Comment: $z=\frac{1}{x}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is of general forms called [Differential Binomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial). There are just 3 possible cases in which you can express the integral as elementary functions (see [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiHos_j_JLXAhWDYlAKHRT8A8IQFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.onu.edu%2F~m-caragiu.1%2Fbonus_files%2FCHEBYSHE.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0T_mnusXmUo3kLl3LN36JZ)). According to it, what the other answer suggested is applicable. It means that you can think on $$t=-1+x.$$ In fact, $a=-1,b=1,p=-3,m=-2$ while $(m+1)/n=-1\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{1}{x^2(x-1)^3}=\left( x-1 \right) ^{-3}-2\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-2}-{x}^{-2}+3\,
 \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}-3\,{x}^{-1}
$$